# Can't upgrade to Laravel 8

Tags: laravel, composer-php, vonage

I am trying to upgrade (from 7 following https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/upgrade).

```
Problem 1
    - Installation request for nexmo/client ^2.0 -> satisfiable by nexmo/client[2.0.0].
    - Can only install one of: guzzlehttp/guzzle[7.0.1, 6.5.x-dev].
    - Can only install one of: guzzlehttp/guzzle[7.0.x-dev, 6.5.x-dev].
    - Can only install one of: guzzlehttp/guzzle[7.1.x-dev, 6.5.x-dev].
    - Conclusion: install guzzlehttp/guzzle 6.5.x-dev
    - Installation request for guzzlehttp/guzzle ^7.0.1 -> satisfiable by guzzlehttp/guzzle[7.0.1, 7.0.x-dev, 7.1.x-dev].
```

Is this because nexmo requires:

```
requires
php >=7.1
php-http/guzzle6-adapter ^2.0
nexmo/client-core ^2.0
Which locks it to guzzle6?
```

Comment: `nexmo/client` need to support  `laravel 8` then only u can use that wait for some day

Answer (score 0):

As written in the [documentation of that package](https://github.com/Nexmo/nexmo-php-complete), you can also install `nexmo/client-core` along with any other package that provides `php-http/client-implementation` - that makes you independent from Guzzle 6.

But you should also check which other package requires Guzzle 7. This is still a somewhat new version (release ten weeks ago), and I don't think that Laravel itself forces you to use Guzzle 7.

Comment: Laravel 8 (laravel/laravel)  "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^7.0.1  https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/composer.json#L14   ...   the upgrade guide specifically tells you to update to this version "guzzlehttp/guzzle to ^7.0.1"

Comment: @lagbox thanks for that hint, I thought that `laravel/laravel`  is only the starting point for a new project (like a skeleton), while `laravel/framework` is the real framework. The second one does allow the usage of Guzzle v6

Comment: `laravel/laravel` is just the skeleton, but the upgrade guide tells you to update your dependencies for the version of guzzle to move to version 8  (i was just showing that Laravel sets that version in fresh installs of 8)

Comment: And what would happen if you just **skip** that part of the documentation?

Comment: idk, I was just showing that Laravel tells people to do this, as you didn't know it was

Comment: This is the correct answer for now. Install `nexmo/client-core`, then install `nexmo/laravel`. We are working on making this a drop-in installation, especially for existing users, but because we supported the PSR-18 wrapper for Guzzle instead of Guzzle directly it's complicated this Laravel upgrade (supporting PSR-18 allowed more clients from various frameworks). I hope to have a full fix out ASAP.